# calculate hash of binary file containing certain bytes

Tags: binaryfiles, sha256

I'm having trouble understanding the principle/method, on how to "manually" calculate a file's hash (sha256) which consist of certain bytes.

To put into an example:

I have this binary file consisting of these bytes.

```
2C F2 BA A3 0E 26 5A 3B  2A 1F 01 4A 01 66 60 02
```

How to get following (correct) hash of the file? `ea3cbd30dc6c18914d2cdafdd8bec0ff4ce5995c7b484cce3237900336abb574`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1.
Convert all bytes to ASCII.

2.
Hash ASCII string to get correct hash from the file.

Doing this manually is not recommended, since e.g. copy and paste, or other factors can easily distort your ASCII string. So optimally this is written within a program to calculate everything altogether.